# Redirect Facebook App To External Page

Tags: facebook, redirect

I'm having issues configuring my Facebook app to behave as I want when posting information via the Feed Dialog. I've set up an app and created a link that correctly posts my content when clicked, but I can't figure out how to make the link to the app in the resulting post redirect where I want it to.

As an example, here's [a post made via Instagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8NhC.png).

If I click on the 'via Instagram' link, I get [either prompted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsyDu.png) or automatically redirected from the destination URL `http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=124024574287414` to `www.instagram.com`.

I've seen other posts suggest you can do something similar using a JavaScript redirect from the App Canvas page, and I've got a proof of concept doing this, but since I've seen Instagram and other apps do this seemingly internally to Facebook I'm convinced it's possible to do more cleanly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That link goes to your app's canvas URL (`apps.facebook.com/something`) or website URL as defined in the app settings, it can't be configured with any more granularity.

Comment: Okay, I see now - I have to enter the site URL in the 'Website with Facebook Login' box. I wish they'd give their options better names!

Answer (score 0):

This seems that it will probably do the trick most easily: http://woobox.com/statichtml

See the redirect radio button in the image they have.